# Mongodb compass and Phpmyamin similarities

Tags: mongodb, phpmyadmin

After a year of going through a boring CLI to interact with my data with mongo client. I found out the best tool i wish i would have get at first time. MongoDb Compass.
After going through all the features, I found the similarity beetween this tools and PhpMyadmin. My question are.

1. How can i view all the query i have executed just like Phpmyadmin console.
2. Is it possible to Export all the query and or Import query to compass just like PhpMyadmin.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your questions. 1. How can all of the query what? 2. Do you mean export results from compass?

Comment: @JimWright. 1. How can view a query after it exec 2. Yes. I mean export

Answer (score 0):

Compass is not PhpMyAdmin. PhpMyAdmin allows you to enter and run queries whereas Compass is more like a wrapper around [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), and although it won't give you the query to run you can easily build the query yourself.

Take the following example:

[image: Compass query]

I could build this query like so:

```
db.users.find({ username: 'jim' }, { password: 0 })
        .sort({ created_at: -1 })
        .skip(2)
        .limit(1)
```

To export the result of this query you can use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/). Sadly you can't use the above query for this but you will have to add a separate argument for each section. You should also note that in the above I exclude `password`, but with mongoexport you are unable to exclude fields - you can only specify which fields to include.

```
mongoexport -d test -c users -q '{ "username": "jim" }, { "password": 0 }' --fields='username,created_at' --sort '{ "created_at": -1 }' --skip 2 --limit 1 --out exported_users.json
```